# How to import my resume pdf file from my local and view in the browser with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am just trying to modify my portfolio. What I want to do is when I click the button to view my resume from local then it pops up in the browser.

greeting.js

```
<div className="button-greeting-div">
                <Button text="Contact me" href="#contact" />
                <Button
                  text="See my resume"
                  newTab={true}
                  href={greeting.resumeLink}
                />
              </div>
```

portfolio.js

```
import emoji from "react-easy-emoji";
import pdf from "./public/ABCResume.pdf";


const greeting = {
  username: "ABC",
  title: "Hi all, I'm ABC",
  subTitle: emoji(
    "A passionate junior Front-end Developer."
  ),
  resumeLink: pdf("ABCResume"),
  displayGreeting: true,
```

the pdf file is in the public folder and the error message is

```
./src/portfolio.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './public/ABCResume.pdf' in 'C:\Users\Desktop\react\portfolio-react-cp\src'
```

I have been searching it for hours and hours. could not figure out.

Comment: you have public folder inside src folder?

Comment: No the public folder is outside src folder.

Comment: you have to put pdf file in src folder and import pdf from "./ABCResume.pdf"

Comment: Thank you Chinh, that works and one thing I needed to do is to delete ("ABCResume") in my portfolio.js. I don't know why I have to delete. but it works.

Comment: because pdf variable is not function when you call pdf("ABCResume")